# Exponent of a stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a square $n \times n $ stochastic matrix $G = \left( g_i^j \right)$, such that:

- $ 0 \leq g_i^j \leq 1 $,
- $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^n g_i^j = 1 $.

Therefore, $G - I = \left(g_i^j - \delta_i^j\right)$ is a degenerate matrix: the sum of each of its rows is zero and each column is a simple linear combination of others: $\mathbf{g}^j = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{j-1} \mathbf{g}^k + \sum\limits_{k=j+1}^n \mathbf{g}^k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1 - \delta_{jk} \right) \mathbf{g}^k$.

Taking into account this limitation, is there a finite form of the matrix exponent $e^{G - I} = e^{-1}e^G$, and how can it be calculated?

If not, can any of these limits be obtained:

- $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{\left(G - I\right) t}$ or
- $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{\left(G - I\right) t} \mathbf{k}$, where $0 \leq k_i \leq 1$?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, $E$ is the identity matrix, so it commutes with $G$ and you have $$e^{G-E}=e^Ge^{-E}= \frac{e^G}{e}$$

Comment: Yes, but what would $e^G$ be?

Comment: The hypotheses are that $G$ is a (right) stochastic matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix

Comment: Yes, it is either that or very similar. So, we know that there must be a limit, and it is the stationary vector which can be calculated as such. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty. I need to know, whether $e^{G-I}$ is stochastic as well. I suspect, it is, but cannot prove it.

Comment: It seems that I am trying to solve a Chapman-Kolmogorov equation, but with a non-I initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here are a few preliminary observations:

- $\displaystyle e^{t(G-I)}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{i!}(G-I)^i$
- Since $\ G\ $ and $\ {-}I\ $ commute, then\begin{align}e^{t(G-I)}&=e^{-tI}e^{tG}\\&=e^{-t}Ie^{tG}\\&=e^{-t}e^{tG}
   \end{align}
- If $\ J=\Pi^{-1}G\,\Pi\ $ is the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of $\ G\ $, then\begin{align}e^{tG}&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{i!}G^i\\&=\Pi\ \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{i!}J^i\,\Pi^{-1}\\
  &=\Pi\,e^{tJ}\,\Pi^{-1}
   \end{align}
- If $$J=\pmatrix{J_1&0&\dots&0\\
   0&J_2&\dots&0\\
  \vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
  0&0&\dots&J_b}\ ,$$ where$$J_i=\pmatrix{\lambda_i&1&0&\dots&\dots&0&0\\
  0&\lambda_i&1&\dots&\dots&0&0\\
  0&0&\lambda_i&\ddots&&0&0\\
  \vdots&\vdots&&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
  0&0&0&\dots&\ddots&1&0\\0&0&0&\dots&\dots&\lambda_i&1\\0&0&0&\dots&\dots&0&\lambda_i}$$ is the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ block of $\ J\ $, then $$e^{tJ}=\pmatrix{e^{tJ_1}&0&\dots&0\\
   0&e^{tJ_2}&\dots&0\\
  \vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
  0&0&\dots&e^{tJ_b}}\ ,$$and $\ e^{tJ_i}\ $ is an upper triangular matrix whose entry in its $\ j^\text{th}\ $ row and $\ (j+k)^\text{th}\ $ column, with $\ k\ge0\ $, is $\ \frac{t^k}{k!}e^{\lambda_it}\ $.

From the results quoted in the first three dot points above, it can be established that $\ e^{t(G-I)}\ $ is stochastic. First, $\ G^i\ $ is stochastic for every $\ i\ $. Therefore, every entry of
$$
e^{t(G-I)}=e^{-t}e^{tG}=e^{-t}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{i!}G^i
$$
is non-negative, and
\begin{align}
e^{t(G-I)}\mathbf{1}_{n\times1}&=e^{-t}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{i!}G^i\mathbf{1}_{n\times1}\\
&=e^{-t}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{i!}\mathbf{1}_{n\times1}\\
&=\mathbf{1}_{n\times1}\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ e^{t(G-I)}\ $ is stochastic.

The third and fourth dot points provide what I would call a "finite form" for $\ e^{t(G-I)}\ $.

You can regard $\ G\ $ as the transition matrix of a finite-state Markov chain.  The states of such a chain can be partitioned into:

- A (possibly empty) set of [transient states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Markov_chain#Transience_and_recurrence);
- A finite number of [communication classes](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eww2040/4701Sum07/4701-06-Notes-MCII.pdf) of states, at least one of which is non-empty.

The matrix $\ G\ $ then has the form
$$
G=U^{-1}\pmatrix{G_1&0_{n_1\times n_2}&\dots&0_{n_1\times n_c}&0_{n_1\times t}\\
0_{n_2\times n_1}&G_2&\dots&0_{n_2\times n_c}&0_{n_2\times t}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0_{n_c\times n_1}&0_{n_c\times n_2}&\dots&G_c&0_{n_c\times t}\\
T_1&T_2&\dots&T_c&T_t}U\ ,
$$
for some suitable permutation matrix $\ U\ $, where $\ t\ $ is the number of transient states, $\ c\ $ the number of communication classes, $\ n_i\ $ the number of states in the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ communication class, and each $\ G_i\ $ is an $\ n_i\times n_i\ $ [irreducible](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html) stochastic matrix. The matrix sequence  $\ G^r\ $  converges as $\ r\rightarrow\infty\ $ if and only if all of the Markov chains corresponding to the matrices $\ G_i\ $ are [aperiodic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Markov_chains#Discrete_Time_Markov_Chains), and, in that case, $\ e^{t(G-I)}\ $ also converges as $\ t\rightarrow\infty\ $, and
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{t(G-I)}&=\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}G^r\\
&=U^{-1}\pmatrix{\mathbf{1}_{n_1\times1}\pi_1^T&0_{n_1\times n_2}&\dots&0_{n_1\times n_c}&0_{n_1\times t}\\
0_{n_2\times n_1}&\mathbf{1}_{n_2\times1}\pi_2^T&\dots&0_{n_2\times n_c}&0_{n_2\times t}\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0_{n_c\times n_1}&0_{n_c\times n_2}&\dots&\mathbf{1}_{n_c\times1}\pi_c^T&0_{n_c\times t}\\
0_{t\times n_1}&0_{t\times n_w}&\dots&0_{t\times n_c}&0_{t\times t}}U\,
\end{align}
where $\ \pi_i^T\ $ is the (unique) $\ 1\times n_i\ $ probability row vector satisfying the equation
$$
\pi_i^TG_i=\pi_i^T\ .
$$
I believe that $\ e^{t(G-I)}\ $ in fact always converges as $\ t\rightarrow\infty\ $, even when some of the $\ G_i\ $ are periodic, but I don't have any very clear ideas about how to go about proving it.

Answer (score 0):

My current understanding of the problem:

What I described seems to be a [Continious-time Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain) (thanks, @Travis_Willse) with a transition rate matrix $G - I$ and an initial state (see also [Kolmogorov equations (continuous-time Markov chains)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equations_(continuous-time_Markov_chains))).

There seems to be no universal finite form for the exponent $e^{G - I}$; the simple case of two states cannot be automatically extended even to three.

If the states were discrete, some of them could be steady, i.e. eigenvectors of $e^{G - I}$ with eigenvalue one, normalised, so that the sum of probabilities is one.

However, since I chose the states to belong to real vector space, the "stationary" states could be only asymptotically approached. However, these limits will be the same, as steady discret states.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).